# Dynamically measured measure (MDX)

Tags: ssas, mdx, member, measure

good night!

I'm new to the MDX world and I'm having a hard time creating a calculated measure, the problem is this: I have a measure that is calculated using the final balance of the previous month as the balance of the current month. Something similar to what they see below.

[This is how the data should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrNfn.jpg)
The problem is that the mdx script I did not add the previous data to the display and so it ends up showing me an incorrect initial value. In the image above it should return the final balance calculated from the beginning of the company to the selected filter. Can anyone help me?

[This is how it is showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDE9Z.jpg)
Here is the mdx query I created:

with Member [Saldo Final 2] as
    ([Measures].[Certificados Novos] + [Measures].[Reativados] - [Measures].[Cancelados Menor ou Igual a 6 Parcela] - [Measures].[Cancelados Maior que a 6 Parcela])
member [Saldo Final Mês Anterior 2] as
    (ParallelPeriod ([DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].[MES ANO]
           , 1
           , [DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].CurrentMember
        ), [Saldo Final 2])
member [Saldo Inicial 2] as
    Sum([DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].CurrentMember.FirstSibling:[DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].CurrentMember, [Saldo Final Mês Anterior 2])
member [Final] as
    [Saldo Inicial] + [Measures].[Saldo Final 2]

select  [DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].[MES ANO] on columns,
        {[Measures].[Certificados Novos], [Measures].[Reativados], [Measures].[Cancelados Menor ou Igual a 6 Parcela], 
            [Measures].[Cancelados Maior que a 6 Parcela], [Final]
            } on rows
    from [dw_sinaf]
where 
{[DIM TEMPO].[ANO].&[2016]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's exactly what are you looking for, but I was able to do it on a simplified model:

Two measures are available:

1. Sales Only Units
2. Return Only Units

We need to have a SUM for every Day (Month in your example) running month-by-month from the initial Date.

Code for FINAL and INICIAL is here:

```
with member [Final] as
([Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Date].&[20170501]
,[Measures].[Sales Only Units])
+
SUM([Date].[Year Qtr Month].[Date].&[20170501]
:[Date].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember
,[Measures].[Return Only Units])

member [Inicial] as
([Final]-[Measures].[Return Only Units])

select non empty [Date].[YQM].[Date].members on 0
,{[Inicial],[Measures].[Sales Only Units],[Measures].[Return Only Units],[Final]} on 1
from [My_Cube]
```

[image: Running_Value]

BLUE is initial value "from the beginning of the company"

RED values to use if required to use another initial date

GREEN required running value

[Sales Only Units] should be ideally hidden for every member, except initial date in order not to confuse business users.

Comment: I made some changes to the script and I was able to find the starting balance, which solves my problem in parts. The new problem is when you filter the time dimension that ends up breaking the sequence, so the accumulated one does not work properly. I need the user-made filter to not interfere with this so I can calculate at any level.

Comment: That's what I need.

with member [Saldo Inicial] as
 SUM(NULL:Axis(0).Item(0).Item(Axis(0).Item(0).Count-1).Hierarchy.PrevMember, [Measures].[Saldo Final AUX]) 

select 
  Filter([DIM TEMPO].[MES ANO].[MES ANO], [DIM TEMPO].[ANO].&[2002] OR [DIM TEMPO].[ANO].&[2004]) on columns,
  {[Saldo Inicial]} on rows
 from [dw_sinaf]

Comment: And that's what happens when I use the filter.

with member [Starting Balance] as
SUM (NULL: Axis (0) .Item (0) .Item (Axis (0) .Item (0) .Count-1) .Hierarchy.PrevMember, [Measures].

select
[DIM TEMPO]. [MONTH YEAR] .Members on columns,
- [Time]] [MONTH YEAR] [MONTH YEAR], [DIM TIME]. [YEAR]. & [2002] OR [DIM TEMPO]
{[Initial Balance]} on rows
from [dw_sinaf]
Onde
{[DIM TIME]. [YEAR]. & [2002],
[DIM TIME]. [YEAR]. & [2004]}